# Recursively converting .jpeg images

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to convert a large number of .jpg files to the medical image format .dcm.  There are many folders (with no subfolders) within a directory called C:\dicom. Each of these contains a patient specific .jpg called "REF.jpg" that needs to be converted to a file called "request.dcm" by using a small utility called **img2dcm** located in C:.

Each folder also contains a patient specific file called "IMG.dcm" used as a template for the conversion.Patient specific metadata is inserted from the template into the newly created request.dcm file.

For an individual folder called "foldername" containing the "REF.jpg" file, and the template file "IMG.dcm", the following command line (including the spaces) will create a usable "request.dcm" file in the same folder:

*img2dcm foldername\REF.jpg foldername\request.dcm -stf foldername\IMG.dcm -k "Ser
iesDescription"=REQUEST -k "Modality"=OT -k "SeriesNumber"=200 -k "ImageNumber"=
1"*

What I need to do is create a batch file to loop this command through every folder in the directory, all differently named but all containing the required files. It is crucial the newly created file be placed within its parent folder.

Any help would be greatly appreciated for what is a fairly daunting project for a someone without an IT or computing background.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
c:
cd \dicom
for /d %%i in (*) do (
 img2dcm c:\dicom\%%i\REF.jpg c:\dicom\%%i\request.dcm -stf c:\dicom\%%i\IMG.dcm -k "Ser iesDescription"=REQUEST -k "Modality"=OT -k "SeriesNumber"=200 -k "ImageNumber"= 1"
)
```

should accomplish this.

I'd suggest you copy a portion of your data to a test subdirectory (say `C:\DUMMY`) and run that routine - having changed `dicom` throughout to `dummy`